# self-signed certificates with limited client

Tags: security, ssl, ssl-certificate, self-signed

Is it safe to use self-signed certificates for my server which will be accessed by limited number of known clients in production? 
To be more clear , my service is not public like Facebook or Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any certificate the client will accept is 'safe', *provided* the client isn't insanely programmed to accept *any* certificate, and unfortunately many are. So whether it's safe in your case depends on how you implement it.

If you do so correctly, i.e. by distributing the certificate to the client truststores, it is safe. However this distribution is itself a problem, and it recurs every time the certificate expires.

The truth is that self-signed certificates were always more trouble than they were worth, and now that SSL certificates can be obtained free they aren't worth anything. So every extra step you have to take because it's self-signed is a cost.

Comment: Thats a reasonable anwser ,but I still confused

Comment: You saying its safe ,but not worthy ,and didnt explain enough  why its not worthy.

Comment: I didn't say 'worthy', I said 'worth', in an answer that explains *exactly* why: the distribution problem, and its recurrence on every expiry. NB 'safe' and 'not worth anything' are not mutually exclusive.

Answer (score -1):

In your case, I would suggest that this is fine.  I think [This](https://www.sslshopper.com/article-when-are-self-signed-certificates-acceptable.html) briefly outlines what you're trying to do:

Comment: still not convinced by this link, thank you by the way.

Comment: Far too many mistakes in that link for it to be cited as evidence. For example, a web server doesn't 'require a certificate so that it can do the encryption.' The 'The biggest problem with a self-signed certificate is a man-in-the-middle attack' only under the conditions outlined in my answer. 'It all comes down to, can you determine that you are using the same crypto key that the server is?' is complete nonsense. 'Before you can begin encrypted communications, you must do an *unencrypted* key exchange, where the server gives you it's crypto key' ditto. Basically it is garbage.

Comment: I agreed with you